# cant see my blog post on my django website

Tags: python, django, django-models

im trying to follow this django tutorial, there a three section on my website called home blog and content.

what should happen, is i click on blog and it list out the blog post i made in the admin and i can click on the post and read what the blog post says, but when i click on blogs nothing shows up, its just blank.

i have already installed apps in settings

i added the url in the url.py folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

I went into the models folder and created a model

from django.db import models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in my blogs/urls folder i have

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [ path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                    template_name="blog/blog.html")),
                path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Post,
                    template_name='blog/post.html'))]
```

in my blog folder i made a new directory called templates and in templates i made another directory called blog and in the folder i made an html file called blog.html and it is in a notepad++. this is what is in that blog.html notepad

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in obejects_list %}
      <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href=
      "/blog/{{post.id}}"> {{post.title}}</a></h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and i went into admin folder and added

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

Comment: You have a typo in the template: `obejects_list`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add **context_object_name** to your ListView class like this :

```
 path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                    template_name="blog/blog.html", context_object_name = "posts")),
```

then in your template do like this :

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href=
      "/blog/{{post.id}}"> {{post.title}}</a></h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```